# how do I select an atom using pymol?

Tags: visualization, scientific-computing

I'm not sure if this is the right web page to ask...

I have a xyz file I have generated:

```
   C   0   0   0
   O   0   0   0.1
   O   0   0   0.2
   C   0   0   0.6
   O   0   0   0.5
   O   0   0   0.4
   .
   .
   .
```

How can I select a specific atom in command line or measure the distance between two atoms (pymol)?

Comment: If `pymol` is a programming language and this is a programming question, then it is the right site. If not, it isn't.

Comment: I assume C and O represent individual molecules? When you say you want to select a specific atom on the command line, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @arunkumar There is a command line interface to pymol, I want to type there ``select whatever`` to select the atom. C and O are not molecules per se as I am doing a coarse grain simulation. I am considering them as atoms (single, not connected sphere).

Answer (score 3):

pymol `select` command is described in detail here:
http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Property_Selectors

In your case, to select certain atom(s), you can use:

```
select C_atoms, name C # select all C atoms and name the selection C_atoms
select atom_4, id 4    # select the 4th atom in the file and name it atom_4
select idx_4, index 4  # 
select rank_4, rank 4  #
```

as for the difference between `rank, ID, index` for atoms, see

http://www.mail-archive.com/pymol-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg08503.html

Answer (score 1):

I have sent an email to the pymol email-list. I need to find the ID of the atom/molecule I want (I'm sure there is a better way but I have used the gui interface) and then:

`select id <num>`

or

`distance id<num>, id<num>`

to measure distance